# Autogrow ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, autogrow

I did search around various questions related to the one I'm about to ask. I just want to ask it in clear and simple manner and hopefully get a clear and simple answer :)

I have a `List` of several hundred items that I want to present to the user in `ListView` widget. Initially I want to start with say 50 items and as user scrolls near the bottom I want to add another 50 and so forth. I think GMail Inbox would be a good example of what I need. I'm not interested in `Cursor` implementation - the dataset is quite simple as I said for now it's just a `List`.

Also - say `ListView` grows too big, it would be nice to start chopping it from the top so it behaves as a sliding ruler at it max showing about 200 rows (with 30 viewable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try my [`EndlessAdapter`](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless). It wraps a `ListAdapter` that you supply and lets you load additional data when the user reaches the bottom. You could try also removing items from the top (e.g., `remove()` on `ArrayAdapter`), though I'm a bit nervous about that -- Android might not make the right decisions if, say, your list does not change size but the lineup of rows changes.

Comment: Great! Thanks Mark, I'll give it a shot and report back!

Comment: Did you ever get to try it? I'm just curious about the performance of the endless adapter? 

Thanks,
Faisal

Comment: I did. At the end I didn't go with Mark's code but here's what I found so far: If I simply add items to the adapter these will not show up. I tried view#invalidate and it's of no use. The only way I can make additional items to show up is to call ListView#setAdapter again. No I don't have to recreate an adapter. The problem is - list jumps up to the first item. I'm getting source code to look what is happening in that call, so stay posted

Comment: In attempting something similar, but with a SimpleCursorAdapter, I had the same issue.  Using setAdapter causes the list to refresh & jump to the top...  However, by instead using SimpleCursorAdapter#changeCursor, I was able to update the list without the jump-to-top side effect. Long story short, as CommonsWare mentions in the solution link above, the adapter's data source must be changed for a seamless effect.

Comment: It will not jump to the very first record. The key here is not to add items directly to the internal list of items but to use
android.widget.ArrayAdapter#add()

Comment: example code: if(myAdapter== null){
     myAdapter= new MyAdapter(
       this, R.id.listView,
       DataList);
     ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView))
       .setAdapter(mysAdapter);
    }else{
     myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }