# Android - ListView autogrow is not working as expected

Tags: android, listview, autogrow

This is continuation to the question I already asked a while back. I've been offered [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473355/autogrow-listview-in-android) which is not really working. Anyway - here's the problem/question

I look at some posts from the past and it seems that if I add items to
the ListView adapter it should update itself and user should be able
to scroll to the newly appended items. Unfortunately it's not what I
observe. If I append new items to my existing ArrayAdapter I only will
see updated results if I rerun ListView#setAdapter again. Doing
nothing, invalidating view etc. doesn't do anything. Here's a snippet:

```
SearchItemsAdapter a = (SearchItemsAdapter) listview.getAdapter();
List<SearchItem> values = fetchNextSetOfItems();
a.append(values);
// unless I do this - I will not see the update, but if I do - 
// I'll jump to the top
listview.setAdapter(a);
```

Here's append method:

```
public void append(List<SearchItem> values) {
        this.items.addAll(values);
}
```

Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add items to the `ArrayList`. Add them to the `ArrayAdapter`.

Comment: Thanks sir... can we make the gridview load from the view we added at last, Instead it is now loading from first and then adding the views